# How do I turn this Extension Method into an Extension Property?

Tags: f#

I have an extension method

```
type System.Int32 with
    member this.Thousand() = this * 1000
```

but it requires me to write like this

```
(5).Thousand()
```

I'd love to get rid of both parenthesis, starting with making it a property instead of a method (for learning sake) how do I make this a property?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Jon's answer is one way to do it, but for a read-only property there's also a more concise way to write it:

```
type System.Int32 with
    member this.Thousand = this * 1000
```

Also, depending on your preferences, you may find it more pleasing to write `5 .Thousand` (note the extra space) than `(5).Thousand` (but you won't be able to do just `5.Thousand`, or even `5.ToString()`).

Comment: +1 - I didn't know that the space in `5 .Thousand` would make for valid syntax.

Answer (score 3):

I don't really know F# (shameful!) but based on [this blog post](http://codebetter.com/matthewpodwysocki/2008/09/10/object-oriented-f-extension-everything/), I'd expect:

```
type System.Int32 with  
    member this.Thousand 
      with get() = this * 1000
```

I *suspect* that won't free you from the first set of parentheses (otherwise F# *may* try to parse the whole thing as a literal), but it should help you with the second.

Personally I wouldn't use this sort of thing for a "production" extension, but it's useful for test code where you're working with a lot of values.

In particular, I've found it neat to have extension methods around dates, e.g. `19.June(1976)` as a really simple, easy-to-read way of building up test data. But not for production code :)

Comment: I'm also sad that it won't let me write the extension on all int types at once

Comment: Not for production code because of the overhead (performance) ?

Comment: @Maslow: No, because it's rarely useful in my experience - and using it on a non-constant would look weird (`x.Thousand` for example). I'd rather just show the multiplication, I think. But for creating test data - yay!

Comment: @Jon Indeed, That's a shame.  The community could use your take on things.

Comment: @gradbot: One day, one day. I know I really *should* learn F# :)

Answer (score 2):

It's not beautiful, but if you really want a function that will work for any numeric type, you can do this:

```
let inline thousand n =
  let one = LanguagePrimitives.GenericOne
  let thousand = 
    let rec loop n i =
      if i < 1000 then loop (n + one) (i + 1)
      else n
    loop one 1
  n * thousand

5.0 |> thousand
5 |> thousand
5I |> thousand
```

Comment: Yikes - you can get away with way fewer arithmetic operations than that...  Something like: `let one = ...; let two = one+one; let ten = two*(two+two+one); ten * ten * ten`.

Comment: Yes, it could be much more efficient. Ideally, you would compute one thousand once and store it as a module member. Then the mechanism for computing it becomes inconsequential.

Comment: Sure, that's possible too: `type ThousandCache< ^a when ^a : ...> = static let thousand = ... static member inline Thousand = thousand`